# NetBeans sending build to multiple locations

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I was wondering if someone knew how to configure NetBeans to send builds to multiple locations?  I am writing some server code.  Every time I build the code, it gets sent to someplace like this:

```
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Net Beans Projects\MyProject\dist
```

I then need to move that build Jar file to a new location (where my other project will use it). Someplace like:

```
C:\SmartFoxServer_2X\SFS2X\extensions\MyOtherProject
```

Is there a way to configure NetBeans to send the build jar file to both locations?  FYI, I am using NetBeans IDE 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NetBeans' "native" project system which is based on Ant, you can customize the build.xml used for your project.

In your case you need to add the "hook" `-post-jar` to your project's `build.xml`

```
<target name="-post-jar">
  <copy overwrite="true" file="${dist.jar}" todir="C:/SmartFoxServer_2X/SFS2X/extensions/MyOtherProject"/>
</target>
```

The `build.xml` can be opened from the "Files" Window (expand the node for your project):

[image]

The `build.xml` also contains a lot of examples and explanations on which hooks are available for you to use.

---

But in general this should not be necessary if the other project is also a NetBeans project. Just add `MyProject` to the other's project classpath.

In the project properties select the Libraries node, then click on the "Add Project" button. The referencing project will then automatically know which jar file to use. You can also tell NetBeans to build `MyProject` when you build `OtherProject`:

[image: project properties]

Comment: In my case, my other project is in Unity, so just adding the XML node to the Build file worked like a charm.  +1 such an in-depth response